# How can I check if a firewall rule exists for a specific program? (Using CMD)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, firewall, rules

I have a batch file which checks if a rule exists searching by name, but I need to search using the program's name, is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow.  Please take the [tour]. Please read [ask] a question and please also read [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `tasklist` and pipe the `find` to search a specific program, like so:

```
tasklist /v | findstr "photoshop.exe"
```

You can read more about tasklist [here](https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html).

Comment: How exactly does this code check a firewall rule?